# Python dataframe to csv index error

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run a python code to load data from one csv to another. i am using pandas to load data from the feed csv to a data frame and then appending that data frame to the final csv

the challenge is that this process will repeat every 1 min, and will append to the existing csv. I am not an expert at python and my code is iffy at best. but here it goes.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import datetime
import time

while True:
  df = pd.read_csv('Feed.csv')
  df['timestamp'] = dt.datetime.now()

  f = open('Final.csv', 'a')
  df.to_csv(f, header = False)
  f.close()
time.sleep(60)
```

The challenge is Final.csv has a id column which is being fed the index. and each time the code runs, the index is starting from 0 again. I have to also load the Final.csv into a mysql table every time, and the id is to serve as the pk. is there anyway to have the id auto increase each time i load it into Final.csv?

thanks

Comment: can you show what is the index? the question does not have enough information for an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can assign in each loop new index values created with previous `max` index value, for `append` to `csv` is better use parameter `mode='a'`:

```
last_idx = 0
while True:
    df = pd.read_csv('Feed.csv')
    df.index = np.arange(last_idx, df.index.max() + last_idx + 1)
    last_idx = df.index.max() + 1
    #print (df)

    df.to_csv('Final.csv', mode='a', header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a piece of code to rewrite your data frame as below in your program.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':range(1,len(df)+1), 'Name':df['Name'], 'Age':df['Age'], 'Salary':df['salary']})
```

Also, you can change the parameters in the function range() so that the initial number of Id column can be any number you want.

And remember when using to_csv() function, set another parameter to be False like this:

```
df.to_csv(f, header = False, index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a counter and set the index using the "index" property of DataFrame in the loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import datetime
import time

count = 0
while True:
    df = pd.read_csv('Feed.csv')
    df['timestamp'] = dt.datetime.now()

    df.index=range(count, count+len(df))
    count += len(df)
    f = open('Final.csv', 'a')
    df.to_csv(f, header = False)
    f.close()
    time.sleep(60) # I assume you're missing an indent here?
```

By the way, for more efficient I/O, I'd suggest to keep the file open rather than open/close in every loop.